# How do I stop ViewState issues once and for all

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a website and whenever I try to add a form with an on button click event to a page I get,

The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

But it only happens sometimes.

I have tried this.EnableViewState = true; and this.EnableViewState = false;  and it makes no difference.

Why does it sometimes work and other times not work and how can I fix it?

Comment: Move to MVC if thats an option..

Comment: @AyKarsi, I can always use a laugh…lol. If you had have put that up as an answer I would have given you the answer! I only work with MVC these days and hate Webforms with a passion! Unfortunately this site is huge and will not be migrated at this stage, I think I may have to build the form in MVC and add it as an iFrame! The only problem there is dynamically lengthening the iFrame as it’s a comment box. Any ideas??? Cheers

Comment: don't like Iframe to much myself. How implementing the form posting etc. using ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m never using Webforms again!

I’ve tried everything to stop the _VIEWSTATE issue and to no avail!

In this instance I was lucky and have created a work around.

The back end to the blog is all MVC4 and was easy to build. The front end is now a blog post, with published comments done in Webforms under it and I’ve included an MVC4 comment box in an iFrame.

For this project, all comments have to be moderated, so the comments are not available to view right away anyway, the user gets a return RedirectToAction("CommentResponse"); page and if I like what they have said their comment will be available to view next time they come to the site.

I think that will work for them and just to re state; I’m never using Webforms again, AyKarsi, I don’t like iFrames either but it works and your initial comment was the correct answer!

Comment: Funny how a decade's worth of ASP.NET users don't have this problem.

Comment: What do you think the problem would be then??? I have no idea! All the documentation on the net I can find, suggests things from, there is a bug in .NET2, but I’m using .NET4 to including enableViewStateMac="false" maxPageStateFieldLength="1000", I’ve tried it all and I still get the error but only “sometimes”! That said, I don’t seem to get the error in FF! As for a decade of Webforms, I was building web sites 5 years prior to that, Classic ASP, PERL but when Webforms came along I built sites in PHP, until I was pointed in the direction of MVC. I’m not a beginner, I’m just new to SO!

Comment: My point about decades of users is that most people don't have this problem, so if you're having the problem it must be due to the _specifics_ of what you're doing. And you didn't _tell_ us the specifics.